# show toast if no result

Tags: java, android

I'm using a filtering SearchView. Everything works fine but, I want show toast if no result..

how can do? thank you

I've posted my code below, so any help would be great......

I don't put any code there because I don't know how to display "no result(s) found"

CustomFilter.java

```
 public CustomFilter(ArrayList<Player> filterList, MyAdapter adapter)
    {
        this.adapter=adapter;
        this.filterList=filterList;

    }

    //FILTERING OCURS
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        //CHECK CONSTRAINT VALIDITY
        if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
        {
            //CHANGE TO UPPER
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            //STORE OUR FILTERED PLAYERS
            ArrayList<Player> filteredPlayers=new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
            {
                //CHECK
                if(filterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    //ADD PLAYER TO FILTERED PLAYERS
                    filteredPlayers.add(filterList.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.count=filteredPlayers.size();
            results.values=filteredPlayers;
        }else
        {
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;

        }


        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

       adapter.players= (ArrayList<Player>) results.values;

        //REFRESH
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

myadapter.java

```
  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return players.size();
    }

    //RETURN FILTER OBJ
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filter == null) {
            filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this);
        }

        return filter;
    }
}
```

Comment: `setEmptyView()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, declare a `Context mcontext` variable in your `CustomFilter.java` then accept a Context in your constructor like this

```
Context mcontext;
    public CustomFilter(ArrayList<Player> filterList, MyAdapter adapter, Context con)
        {
            this.adapter=adapter;
            this.filterList=filterList;
            this.mcontext=con;
        }
```

On your `publishResults` method check if result count is 0 or not.

If it is 0 then show a toast like this.

```
if(results.count==0)
{
 Toast.makeText(mcontext, "No results...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

else
{

adapter.players= (ArrayList<Player>) results.values; 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: @M.bala7 While creating the object of the class `CustomFilter` pass the context in the last place. Can you show how you are creating the object so that I can help you more.

Comment: @M.bala7 Can your post the line of code for which the error was shown.

Comment: @M.bala7 OK. Change this line `filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this);` to `filter = new CustomFilter(filterList, this, yourActivityName.this);` And also don't forget to replace `yourActivityName` with the name of your class in which this code is present. Are you calling this code from an adapter?

Comment: @M.bala7 If you are calling it from an adapter then please also post your adapter code and how you are setting the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can put below line in your code where you do not find any result.

`Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();`

You can obtain context object like below,

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

`text` is any string/message that you want to show to use like "No result found"

```
CharSequence text = "No Results found";
```

`duration` you can set as `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`

Comment: well, the full code is 1 line...all you need to do is put `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();` in YOUR CODE where you want to show code. Don't you know that?